# Hibernate selecting records from one to many relationship not working

Tags: java, hibernate

Am selecting records based on some condition and its working fine. Please find the query below., which was working as expected.

```
Select req1 from UserRequest as req1 where and req1.fullyApproved = true and  req1.createdAt=(select max(createdAt) from UserRequest req2 where req1.userRequestName=req2.userRequestName)
```

Please find the model class for UserRequest table.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_requests")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserRequest implements Identifiable<Long>, LazilyLoadable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "supervisor_name")
    private String supervisorName;

    @Column(name="fully_approved")
    private boolean fullyApproved;

    @Column(name="user_request_name")
    private String userRequestName;


    @Transient
    @JsonProperty
    private User user;
}   


Please find the model class for User

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"username"})
@ValidDsdPermissions
@ValidApprovalPrivileges
public class User implements Identifiable<Long>, LazilyLoadable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @JsonProperty("userLink")
  private Long id;

  @NotEmpty(message = "{error.model.user.attribute.username.required}")
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String full_name;


  @NotEmpty(message = "{error.model.user.attribute.email.required}")
  @Email(message = "{error.model.user.attribute.email.format.invalid}")
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String email;

@Column(name = "is_active")
private boolean active = true;


  }
```

From this two model class `full_name` & `supervisor_name` are same.

I have added one more condtion here before selecting records. ( u.active=true)

( u is the object of User table ) . This query is not working as expected - `u.active=true` is not satisfying.

```
Select req1 from User u, UserRequest as req1 where u.active=true and req1.fullyApproved = true and  req1.createdAt=(select max(createdAt) from UserRequest req2 where req1.userRequestName=req2.userRequestName)
```

How can i modify this query.?

Comment: looks like your property name is "is_active" and in your query you write active=true, maybe you got mixed up there? try u.is_active=true

Comment: The query is not working because you didn't join the tables. `from User u, UserRequest as req1` you have to join, right now you have produced a Cartesian product from both tables

Comment: @JorgeCampos - can you help me out how to join both tables.?

Comment: The problem here is that you designed your UserRequest to not be linked with user (your user attribute in UserRequest is not linked at all with User it is even marked as transient). If you want to do that you need to create this link between then. Take a look at this article and see the Mobile class and how is its relation with user: https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-mapping